# Contour of 2d point clouds

Tags: 3d, 2d, point-clouds, geometry-surface, marching-cubes

I have scattered point clouds in 2d. My problem is I would like to get the boundary's point to get the contour of the point clouds.

I know about this 'marching square' however this algorithm usually used for pixel in 2d.
Any one have idea how to get the contour from 2d point clouds or details of 'Marching square' algorithm? In addition, convex hull does not work in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that a marching squares approach is still your best bet. (Anyone please correct me if I'm wrong). You would map your 2d points to "pixel" values, updating the density of points around that pixel. So if many points are close to a certain pixel, the density is higher than when there is just one on top or nearby. From there on you would proceed with Marching Squares.

Comment: thanks.can you please explain what do you mean by map my 2d points to 'pixel'?

Comment: I was thinking of something similar to metaballs in 3D (or you might have a look at surface reconstruction methods for SPH fluid simulations). This link contains mostly what I'm hinting at: http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/BLOBS/blobs.html Now of course you would ignore the 3D and the ray casting. Would something like that suit you? Another interesting link might be this: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch07.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the 2D "Alpha shapes" algorithm would the right choice for you.

http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html

Alpha shapes can be considered as a generalization for the "convex Hull" algorithm that allows for generation of more general shapes.

By using alpha shapes you will be having control over the level of details to be captured by the resultant shape by changing the alpha parameter value.

You can try the java applet here : http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/belair/alpha.html

to have better understanding about does this algorithm do.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) as a base algorithm, then removing all triangles which are too big (thus splitting the clouds to groups), then removing all edges used by more than one triangle.